# How can I cast a currentValueSubject to non-mutable observable?

Tags: ios, swift, combine

So I'm much more familiar with `RxSwift` than `Combine`. A good way I manage mutable/immutable interfaces is I do something like this in `RxSwift`

```
protocol SampleStream {
   /// An immutable interface. 
   var streamInfo: Observable<String?> { get} 
}

protocol MutableSampleStream: SampleStream {
   /// A mutable interface. 
   func updateStream( _ val: String?)
}

func SampleStreamImpl: MutableSampleStream {

   // Returns the immutable version of the stream.
   // If I pass down SampleStream as a dependency, then nothing else can write to this stream.
   // When they subscribe, they immediately get a value though since it's a behavior subject. 
   var streamInfo: Observable<String?> {
      return streamInfoSubject.asObservable()
   }

   private var streamInfoSubject = BehaviorSubject<String?>(value: nil) 

   func updateStream { }
}
```

How can I do something similar using `Combine`? Combine's `currentValueSubject` doesn't appear to have a way to cast this down to a non-read write version. Or am I missing something?

In my app, I don't want to directly pass down a `currentValueSubject` since I know for a fact I only want this stream updated from one place. Everywhere else should just read from the stream and not have write capability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `AnyPublisher` as your non-mutable type:

```
protocol SampleStream {
    var streamInfo: AnyPublisher<String?, Error> { get }
}

protocol MutableSampleStream: SampleStream {
    func updateStream(_ val: String?)
}

class MySampleStream: MutableSampleStream {
    var streamInfo: AnyPublisher<String?, Error> {
         return subject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    func updateStream(_ val: String?) { subject.send(val) }

    private let subject = CurrentValueSubject<String?, Error>(nil)
}
```

Comment: Nice - thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for. I suppose I did not find this obvious in the documentation for `eraseToAnyPublisher ` but this is what I want!

Comment: This makes the subject imutable but you also lose the option to read the last emited value which CurrentValueSubject offers

Comment: That is true. AFAIK, Combine doesn't currently have any type or protocol that allows reading but not writing the current value. If you want one, you'll have to implement it yourself.

Comment: Well @MihaiDamian - the last value should still emit when a subscription is made. A very simple solution to seeing the last value would just be to include a non-reactive API  so something like `var currentStreamInfo: String?` if it's fine that a consumer does not need to react to a change (like in a take(1) kind of case).